# BoxFit.fill shrinks the image,while BoxFit.Cover leads to hide some parts of the image

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Ima trying to use an image in a circular shape, but it always leads to the issue of either cutting parts at the edge of the image, or shrinking the image in a bad way that is not good for the design...Have used DecorationImage, CircleAvatar, and ClipOval and all of them lead to the same issue.
[image: in case of boxFit.Cover]

[image: in case of boxFit.Fit]

Answer (score 1):

Use `BoxFit.contain` to keep the aspect ratio of the image and not cut out parts. It's like the combination of BoxFit.width and BoxFit.height.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have issue with your image's width, you can use `BoxFit.fitWidth`. This would fit image from its width and cut it from its height.